# Plotting variables not showing up in OpenModelica

Tags: ubuntu, modelica, openmodelica

Today, installed OpenModelica in Ubuntu 12.10, and I ran one of the examples in simulation.  It worked fine the first time. Then I closed out the Plotting Variables window in the OpenModelica Editor, and when I run the same simulation again, instead of listing the plotting variables, the window simply shows the path to the .mat file in which the variables should be stored.  How can I restore the default behavior?  Is there a settings file I can delete somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what I did to cause the problem in the first place, but I found the configuration file that was problematic by using the command

```
find -iname '*omedit*'
```

in the home directory and then

```
rm -rf .config/openmodelica/
```

to remove the offending configuration directory.  I did not have any important configuration info anyway so it was ok to start from scratch.  The problem is now solved, and the output variables show up in the "Plot Variables" window.  The plots look great.